# How to insert struct data to a file?

Tags: c++

I've been working on a records system, everything looks good but

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

struct students{
    string studentID;
    string surname;
    string firstname;
    string birthdate;
    string sex;
};

int main()
{
    fstream collection;
    string filename;
    short choice;



    do{
        int ctr=1;
        system("cls");
        if(collection.is_open()){
                cout<<"Active File: ["<<filename<<"]"<<endl;
        }else{
                cout<<"Active File|: [None opened]"<<endl;
        }

        cout<<"[1] Create new file"<<endl;
        cout<<"[2] Open existing file"<<endl;
        cout<<"[3] Manage data"<<endl;
        cout<<"[4] Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter operation index: ";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            cout<<"Enter file name: ";
            cin>>filename;
            collection.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
            collection<<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            collection<<"Rec \t Student ID \t Surname \t Firstname \t Birthdate \t Sex \t"<<endl;
            collection<<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            collection.close();
            collection.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"Enter file name: ";
            cin>>filename;
            collection.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
            break;
        case 3:
            string lines;
            char menu;
            students student[10];

            do{
                ifstream collection(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
                if(collection.is_open()){
                    cout<<"Active File: ["<<filename<<"]";
                    system("cls");
                    while(getline(collection,lines)){
                    cout<<lines<<endl;
                    }
                }
                collection.close();

                cout<<"[A]dd  [E]dit [D]elete  [S]ort  [F]ilter  Sa[V]e  e[X]it";
                cin>>menu;

                if(menu=='A'){
                    string lines2;
                    collection.open(filename,ios::app);
                    system("cls");

                    ifstream collection(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
                        if(collection.is_open()){
                            while(getline(collection,lines)){
                                cout<<lines<<endl;
                            }
                        }

                    cout<<endl<<"Adding data to "<<filename<<endl;
                    cout<<"Student ID: ";
                    cin>>student[ctr].studentID;
                    cout<<"Surname: ";
                    cin>>student[ctr].surname;
                    cout<<"Firstname: ";
                    cin>>student[ctr].firstname;
                    cout<<"Birthdate: ";
                    cin>>student[ctr].birthdate;
                    cout<<"Sex: ";
                    cin>>student[ctr].sex;
```

Why do I keep getting errors here?

```
                    //data insertion code heree
                    collection.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
                    collection<<ctr<<"\t"student[ctr].studentID<<"\t"student[ctr].surname<<"\t"student[ctr].firstname<<"\t"student[ctr].birthdate<<"\t"student[ctr].sex<<endl;

                    collection.close();
                    ctr++;
                }else if(menu=='E'){

                }else if(menu=='D'){

                }else if(menu=='F'){

                }else if(menu=='V'){
                    cout<<"Saving file..."<<endl;
                    collection.close();
                    cout<<"File saved."<<endl;
                    system("pause");
                }else{
                    cout<<"Invalid input."<<endl;
                    system("pause");
                };
            }while(menu!='X');
            break;
        }
    }while(choice!=4);

    }
```

Why am I getting error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'collection << ctr'| errors? The code worked on the early part of the system and it just didn't work.

Comment: This code is probably very much more than a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try to trim it down to as few lines as possible, which still reproduce your problem. **And include the full error message of the compiler.**

Comment: `"\t"student` is missing `<<` between your string literals and your next value. This is rampant on the line you're questioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `collection` in two places, and where you are using it it is an `istream`. You can't output to an ifstream.

You also forgot a bunch of `<<`
This should solve it. You can also open the file directly in the constructor, which would be better.

```
            fstream collection_out;
            collection_out.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
            collection_out << ctr << "\t" << student[ctr].studentID<<"\t" << student[ctr].surname<<"\t"<<student[ctr].firstname<<"\t" << student[ctr].birthdate<<"\t"<< student[ctr].sex<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

`collection` is defined as an `ifstream`, i. e. "input file stream". It only supports reading input *from* a file, thus only `operator>>`.

You need an `ofstream` to output data *to* a file. Or you use an fstream, which supports both input and output.

And WhozCraig pointed to it already: Your code is lacking calls to `operator<<` between several output data.